# xslt transformation for given xml

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is my xml file for which I am to write an xsl file. Purpose for this xsl is to use for xml to html translation using java xml transform.

[image: xml file]

I am trying to implement this logic in my xsl file, but unable to get so.

```
for each loop Id = PO1
    if segment Id = PO1
        if element Id = PO103
            print its value (i.e. CS)
    if loop Id = PID
        if segment Id = PID
            if element Id = PID05
                print its value (i.e. BANANAS, ...)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language is that? Please show us your XSLT file that doesn't work.

Comment: This is just a pseudo-code : an algorithm which xslt file should follow. I am new to xsl/xslt, searched web, but could not find any xslt representation for this type of case, or may be I could not understand what i found there. That's why I posted it here if any of you could help me write xslt code for this logic, or give some hints. thanks.

Comment: Oops, we don't write code here.

Comment: Ya. That's why I was asking for hint or part of code, and I got it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//loop[@Id='PO1']/segment[@Id='PO1']/element[@Id='PO103']
                      |
                      //loop[@Id='PID']/segment[@Id='PID']/element[@Id='PID05'] ">
    <!-- whatever "print" means goes here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

P.S. Please post your XML as *code*, not as picture.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [user3016153](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/user3016153), with your help I could solve my problem like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>HTML generated by XSLT stylesheet from EDI input</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="//loop[@Id='PO1']/segment[@Id='PO1']/element[@Id='PO103']
                      |
                      //loop[@Id='PID']/segment[@Id='PID']/element[@Id='PID05'] ">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```